# Mocking a cotroller context asp 4.5

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, moq

I have to mock the controller context in order to test some methods that are authorized. The problem is that although I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877225/how-do-i-unit-test-a-controller-method-that-has-the-authorize-attribute-applie) it does not work because when I type:

```
var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
```

Visual Studio underlines `ControllerContext` and says that

> The type or namespace could not be found

These are the usings i have included in the unit test class:
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Moq;
    using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
    using Data.Contracts;
    using System.Linq;
    using Web.Api.Controllers;
```

Any ideas how to include `ControllerContext` in the MSDN documentation they say that it is part of System.Web but it does not seem to be working. Also it will be great if there is another way to mock the context without using this.

I fixed the reference by intalling the Mvc package. But now receive the following error when I try this:

```
var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            mock.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("SOMEUSER");
            mock.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
            controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;
```

Cannot convert `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext` to `System.Web.Http.Controllers.ControllerContext`

```
> controller.ControllerContext = mock.Objectt;
```

Comment: Try by removing  using System.Web.Http.Controllers; and use ControllerContext from System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Try to set explicit namespace `new Mock<System.Web.Http.Controllers.ControllerContext>(); `

Comment: Again, does not exist in the current namespace error.

Comment: I'm confused. There is an accepted answer but the question still doesn't seem to have been resolved. Am I mistaken in my assessment?

Comment: The first question was answered, but now has another problem thas was not mentioned before. So @Nkosi should it be the new question or updated current?

Comment: If the answer fully answered the initial question then user should accept that answer, bringing this post to a close. Any other issues should be addressed in a new question. Try to avoid being sucked into a bait and switch situation.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, thanks. I agree.

Comment: So, please @StefanL19 If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ControllerContex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext(v=vs.118).aspx)t is a part of `System.Web.Mvc` in `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. Just add reference to it