# Mocking ControllerContext could not find reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, moq

The problem emerged as a result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432795/mocking-a-cotroller-context-asp-4-5) question. I did the following things:

I fixed the reference by intalling the Mvc package. But now receive the following error when I try this:

```
var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            mock.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("SOMEUSER");
            mock.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
            controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;
```

Cannot convert `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext` to `System.Web.Http.Controllers.ControllerContext`

```
> controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;
```

Any ideas why using `System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext;` is not available in my test project.

Comment: You installed the wrong MVC package. Install the same in your unit test project as you use in your Web Application project.

Comment: It seems that I do not have any MVC package. It is because it is an api project

Comment: ... Then replace "MVC" with "WebAPI" in my previous comment.

Comment: Same error after, checking if the packages are the same. I have installed Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc in both projects. Versions are also the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong packages and the wrong namespaces.

It seems to me that you need to mock `System.Web.Http.Controllers.ControllerContext`, but you are providing a mocking instance of `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext` which is **not** the Web API class, but the ASP.NET MVC one.

What to do:

1. Ensure you have installed *Web Api* package into your Unit Test Project:
   `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`
2. **Remove** any reference of MVC assemblies from your Unit Test Project (of course do this only if you do not need to test MVC components)
3. Ensure you are importing the correct namespaces (and not the MVC ones) inside your Unit Test class:
   `using System.Web.Http.Controllers;`

Please be aware that even if the class names are the same, MVC components and Web API components are *not* interchangeable. Always verify you are using the correct ones inside your project.