# Integration test on controller decorated with [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, bearer-token

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API.

How do I test a controller which is decorated with the `Authorize` attribute?

For example, with this controller and test method:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void GetSomeDataTest()
{
   var controller = new MyController();
   Assert.AreEqual(controller.GetSomeData(), "Test");
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetSomeData()
{
   return this.Content("Test");
}
```

This is just an example code to make it possible for you guys to answer. I am actually invoking the `Controller` via a `TestServer` object.

This has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877225/how-do-i-unit-test-a-controller-method-that-has-the-authorize-attribute-applie) but the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.
Any suggestions how I could "fake" the users' authenticity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a claim principle to the current thread

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>() 
    { 
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "UserName"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TestAuth");
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
}
```

For .NET Core, you could set the user to the controller context

```
private MyController _ctrl;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "UserName"),
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
    }));

    _ctrl = new MyController();
    _ctrl.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
    {
        HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = user }
    };
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetSomeDataTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(_ctrl.GetSomeData(), "Test");
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. Visual studio is giving me an error because of the last line "Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;".
The error is: "Cannot resolve symbol 'CurrentPrincipal'"

Comment: Yes it seems like CurrentPrincipial is deprecated

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt updated my answer. Did not know that the Threding was deprecated in Core.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you are not actually invoking the controller. Rather, you are running a mock test and thus nothing is happening in the conventional way like the ASP.NET engine handling your request -- request passing through HTTP pipeline (thus authorization module).

So while testing, you should only concentrate on the internal logic of the controller action method instead of that `Authorize` attribute because, in your unit test method, no authentication / authorization will take place. You will setup mock and call the controller action method like any other method.

Comment: Hello Rahul thank you for your answer. But would it be possible to test a controller decorated with the [Authorize] attribute? And if so how is it possible?

Comment: Iam actually invoking the controller via TestServer but I just wanted to keep things simple, thats why I postet this piece of code

Comment: Moritz Schmidt, how are you getting around Authorize with TestServer?

Comment: @Brian sorry, I didnt notice your comment until now. I skipped the testing of the controller classes, since it would be way to much effort.